# Regular Expression for HTML

Tags: regex, excel, vba

From this string:

```
<strong class="big zindex-pt zindex-pt-all">&pound;2,362,214</strong>
```

I am trying to get `&pound;2,362,214` using this Regex in Excel VBA:

```
 .Pattern = "<strong class="big zindex-pt zindex-pt-all">([\s\S]*?)<"
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Well, for one thing you're parsing HTML with regular expressions.

Comment: See [this answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/4088852)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape double quotes inside regex: `"` to `""`

Comment: there are a lot of other html lines that I didn't mention in the question.. I need to target this line specifically.

Comment: I am actually getting compile errors in Excel VBA. Somehow I need to exit the quotemarks in my Pattern ?

Comment: In VBA `"` is escaped with `""` (doubled-up quotes)

Answer (score 0):

ok thanks. Actually this works for me:

```
.Pattern = "<strong class=""big zindex-pt zindex-pt-all"">([\s\S]*?)<"
```

Comment: `\S` matches anything that is not `\s` and both of them combined matches anything at all